# NameError: uninitialized constant when accessing one-to-many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm building a simple RoR 4 puzzle game that has a simple one-to-many association...

```
class Puzzle < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :author, class_name: :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :authored_puzzles, foreign_key: :author_id, class_name: :puzzle
end

class AddAuthorIdToPuzzle < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_reference :puzzles, :author_id, index: true
  end
end
```

Works fine when accessing from the Puzzle side...

```
> p Puzzle.first.author
  Puzzle Load (1.1ms)  SELECT  "puzzles".* FROM "puzzles"   ORDER BY "puzzles"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
=> nil
```

But crashes when accessing from the User side...

```
> p User.first.authored_puzzles
  User Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"   ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
NameError: uninitialized constant User::puzzle
```

Help! Thanks in advance for your wisdom!

Comment: Why dont you just do has_many  :puzzles in the user model??

Comment: Because I plan to have other user-to-puzzle associations, so it needs to be named. Is there a problem with the way I'm doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :authored_puzzles, foreign_key: :author_id, class_name: :puzzle
end
```

There's no class called `puzzle`. The class name is `Puzzle`, so you want this:

```
has_many :authored_puzzles, foreign_key: :author_id, class_name: "Puzzle"
```